# How to concatenate fields in the middle of a string url

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a jquery onclick function I want to be assigned to an api, but first I have to perform the concatenation of the address with some fields value, as in the example below.

**The problem is that I am not performing concatenation correctly.**

**This concatenation is incorrect.**

```
var url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=55"+ document.getElementById('Phone').value +" &text=Hellow,%20" + document.getElementById('Copy').value;
```

**JQuery function**

```
    $("#fidelizar").click(function () {

        var url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=55"+ document.getElementById('Phone').value +" &text=Hellow,%20" + document.getElementById('Copy').value;

        window.open(url, '_blank');
    });
```

Comment: `" &text=Hellow,%20"` <-- I see a space there in between query parameters.  Remove it; that shouldn't be there.

Comment: What is the error coming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try some thing like this `var url =`https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=55${$('#Phone').val()} &text=Hellow,%20${$('#Copy').val()}`;` . It is  [string interpolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) here you can embed expressions within normal strings.

```js
$("#fidelizar").click(function () {

        var url = `https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=55${$('#Phone').val()}&text=Hellow,%20${$('#Copy').val()}`;

        window.open(url, '_blank');
        console.log(url);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="Phone" type="text">
<br/>
<input id="Copy" type="text">
<br/>
<button id="fidelizar">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another issue you might be having is that the elements you are retrieving don't have the `value` attribute. You might want to try `console` logging those values to make sure they're not actually undefined first. If those aren't `input text node` types that might be the issue. You'll have to use `nodeValue` or `textContent` instead if you want to get the current text value of the element.